# head() function failing

Tags: r, head, r-haven

I want to use the `head()` function to have an overview of the data set but it doesn't work.

```
> library(haven)
> corona <- read_sav("Corona_FB/Corona_FB/TRR265_CoronaFB_16-12-2020.sav")
> View(corona)
> head(corona)
```

> Error in is.character(subclass) :
> argument "subclass" is missing, with no default

```
> head(corona,n=3)
```

> Error in is.character(subclass) :
> argument "subclass" is missing, with no default

Comment: unfortunately we almost certainly can't answer this question without more information. At the **very** least, what is `class(corona)`?  Can you please post a [mcve] ?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't load any other library? Type `head` into console (without brackets) to see from which namespace is the function

Comment: or `find("head")`

Comment: I imagine @JanKislinger has hit the answer. Try running just the couple of lines of code in a totally fresh R session and see if you get the same issue.

Comment: could you try doing `utils::head(corona)`

Comment: @BenBolker:  > class(corona) [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"   I tried as.data.frame for "corona" and it works but I dont know why. Do you happen to know why?

Answer (score 1):

Since your object is a tibble (class "tbl_df" "tbl" "data.frame"), which is a very widely used object class, the problem is probably with the `head()` function/method. In a **clean** R session (i.e., no other objects in the workspace), with only the `haven` and `tidyverse` packages loaded, this works fine:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(haven)
dd <- tibble(x=1:5,y=2:6)
head(dd)
```

There is about a 99% chance that you have somehow gotten a weird version of `head` defined (a 1% chance that your data object (`corona`) is weird). To be sure that it's not your data object, we would need a **reproducible example**, i.e. you would have to give us access to your data file or to your data object dumped with `save()` or `dput()`).

If `find("head")` returns anything other than "package:utils", then you do indeed have a different `head()` function masking the base-R version. You can make sure you are using the base-R version by using `utils::head()` instead of `head()`. If the weird version of `head()` is in your global workspace (i.e. `find("head")` returns ".GlobalEnv") then you may want to get rid of it by saying `rm("head")`.

Alternatively, as suggested in the comments, you could see if your code works in a **clean** R session, i.e. one where you have no other packages loaded or objects defined in your workspace. (Restarting R usually works, but you need to make sure that you're not restoring a workspace from a previous R session.)

In the meantime, if you want an "overview" of your data set, you could also try `summary()` or `str()`.